# Datetimeoffset not working on azure app service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, datetime, azure-appservice

I am working on a method to query an existing table with one of the columns to be datetimeoffset "2021-02-06 05:00:00.0000000 -04:00"

I have a stored procedure that accepts the startDate and endDate. I want the startDate to be the beginning of the day(startDate) and the end of the day(endDate)

```
 var DateToStartOfDay = StartDate + " 00:00:01.0000000 -04:00";
 var DateToEndOfDay = EndDate + " 23:59:00.0000000 -04:00";
            //DateTimeOffset.Parse
 var startDate = DateTimeOffset.Parse(DateToStartOfDay);
 var endDate = DateTimeOffset.Parse(DateToEndOfDay).AddDays(1);
```

The above code works perfectly on my system  but one I deploy to Azure App Service, I got this error

> String '2018-02-29 23:59:00.0000000 -04:00' was not recognized as a
> valid DateTime."

Comment: 2018 is not a leap year so there is no February 29th

Comment: And this is not just in AppService: https://dotnetfiddle.net/gwTfe0

Comment: Thanks all for pointing that out, I didn't check 2018 to be a leap year

Comment: But I am still getting empty result which is not so on local

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you can set `string` type in `StartDate`.

**My test code**

```
    public string bb(string aa) {
        try
        {
            var DateToStartOfDay = aa + " 00:00:01.0000000 -04:00";
            var startDate = DateTimeOffset.Parse(DateToStartOfDay);
            return startDate.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.ToString();
            throw;
        }
    }
```

**Test Result**

[image]

---

Although the Azure web app runs in the sandbox environment, we can use it as a cloud server. The local effect should be the same as that deployed in the azure web app. If there is still NULL, it is recommended to add try... catch... to catch the exception. Or learn [how to remote debug](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/remote-debugging-azure-app-services/).